# ES: histogram facet with histogram facet with all_terms=true

Tags: elasticsearch

[Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org) [Histogramfacet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/histogram-facet.html) doesn't appear to support all_terms = true (i.e: return facetvalue / bucket even though count=0)

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. However, if you are not using relevancy to sort your results you can move your query into the top-level `filter` element and put `match_all` into the top-level `query` element. For example, for following request will return two histograms - one only with elements that correspond to the query and another one for entire index:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {
        // filter goes here
    },
    "facets": {
        "histo_all": {
            "histogram": {
                "field": "my_field"
            }
        },
        "histo": {
            "histogram": {
                "field": "my_field"
            },
            "facet_filter": {
                // same filter from top-level filter goes here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: alright, staying with my current setup, and just populating facet-values for count=0 in myself. It would be handy though (using sliders with histogram counts in my use-case)

Comment: Can you give an example of the query structure you're referring to, please?

Comment: I have the same problem, so as @ches said is there any example you can provide? I tried many different things but couldnt find anything useful.